# How to safely store various secret keys on server side?

Tags: security, server

Whether it is cookie signing, super user username and password for the database, or JWT token signing, on the server side there are secret keys to secure the action.

However this key is likely just a plain string on the server code. I have been wondering is there any more procedure to protect these key strings on the server side? Concerns about this, for example, if the attacker managed to get an access to the server's `ssh` then he could easily get the key. Or should I assume that I have already lose everything once an attacker can access the server?

(This leads me to assume that putting secrets directly in the code is what everyone is doing and is the common practice.)

Comment: *"attacker managed to get an access to the server's ssh"* – then you're pretty much dead anyway.

Comment: Ok, that might be too harsh, how about just the server codes? (Like Node.js's `server.js` and related files) But initially I think to be able to access those server codes it is likely that the attacker already have an `ssh` access.

Other means might be that the attacker can hack just the SQL db, but then that means if I put the secret keys directly in the code file it will be safer just in case the db got hacked.  (This leads me to assume that putting secrets directly in the code is what everyone is doing)

Comment: You don't put secrets into your VCS repository (which you're using, right?), which means they must not be in code either. You usually put them in config files on the server, or set them up as environment variables for the user running the server. That means if an attacker has access to the code (they have that kind of access to the server) they can likely do the same things as the code can which means they can get the secrets.

Comment: It pretty much boils down to: 1) You don't outright *leak* anything from your server, 2) you do not allow an attacker any sort of access to the server (SSH, FTP, code execution vulnerability in your code etc.). If an attacker can get either of these, you're usually toast and worrying about it in more detail is typically a waste of time.